# "__TFE10FoundationSS9substringfT4fromVVSS13CharacterView5Index_SS", referenced from:

Tags: swift3

When I try to use subString function to get the specific text,

```
var str = "http://wikipedia.org"
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
str.substring(from: index)
```

xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) will prompt an error:

```
  "__TFE10FoundationSS9substringfT4fromVVSS13CharacterView5Index_SS", referenced from:
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: In a playground or a project?